# Raspberry Pi Zero W OS for 1GB SD Card

Tags: pi-zero-w, headless

I got my Raspberry Pi Zero W recently. I have an old 1GB Micro SD Card lying around and would like to try it out with my Pi zero W. Is there any OS which fits on the 1GB Card and will allow me to do headless setup of the Pi Zero W? I do not currently have the mini HDMI to HDMI cable so I can't connect to any screen.

Thanks

Comment: I think only OpenELEC would fit on a 1GB card. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21094

Comment: I tried OpenELEC. But I was unable to SSH to it for a headless setup.

Comment: It needs setting up on a screen so that SSH can be turned on (I think it's on by default). This could be done in another Pi. Don't forget the username in OpenELEC is root with a password of openelec.

Comment: ssh root@192.168.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying either [DietPi](http://dietpi.com/) or [TinyCoreLinux](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/ports.html) to start with.  They offer different experiences based on what you're trying to do.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

As @MrChips said you can use DietPi and TinyCoreLinux. Other than that here are few suggestions.

- [FreeBSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi)
- [PuppyLinux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Download%20Latest%20Release.htm)
- [Risc OS](https://www.riscosopen.org/content/downloads/raspberry-pi)